# Occasional screen flickering after full system update in Arch Linux/KDE Plasma 5

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, kde, graphics

Few days ago I have fully updated Arch system and since then some applications start flickering from time to time, most usually Konsole and Emacs.

Suspicious flickering seemingly appears randomly but it is almost always solved when application is exited (as said, most usually Emacs and Konsole).

Before I start rummage around with drivers I would like to ask:

> Does anyone have any experience with such a flickering? It happens from time to time and it is usually solved when currently used application is shut down.

Changing drivers have not helped me that much in the past. As a rule, those most ubiquitous drivers have shown as best ones.

I have tried to figure out what have caused the behavior but with no success. In favor of having everything what is

System information:

```
OS: Arch Linux 
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.9.65-1-lts
Uptime: 1h 40m
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: KDE 5.40.0 / Plasma 5.11.3
WM: KWin
WM Theme: Breeze
GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: breeze
Font: Noto Sans Regular
CPU: Intel Core i5-5200U @ 4x 2.7GHz [37.0°C]
GPU: intel
RAM: 2195MiB / 7867MiB
```

Xorg server:

```
[novak@thinkpad ~]$ pacman -Qi xorg-server | grep Version
Version         : 1.19.5-1
```

Graphics driver:

```
[novak@thinkpad ~]$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500 [17aa:2227]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Xorg log:

```
[novak@thinkpad ~]$ cat ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     5.642] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.642] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.642] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
```

Systemd does not report any failed services:

```
novak@thinkpad ~]$ systemctl --failed
0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Journal (as long as I know, nothing is related to Xorg, screen or driver):

```
[novak@thinkpad ~]$ journalctl -b | grep -i error
Nov 25 14:27:27 thinkpad kernel: [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
Nov 25 14:27:28 thinkpad kscreen_backend_launcher[630]: kscreen.xcb.helper: Event Error:  147
Nov 25 14:30:15 thinkpad baloo_file_extractor[1840]: "Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)"
Nov 25 14:30:15 thinkpad baloo_file_extractor[1840]: "Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary"
Nov 25 14:30:15 thinkpad baloo_file_extractor[1840]: "Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary"
Nov 25 14:30:15 thinkpad baloo_file_extractor[1840]: "Error: Couldn't read xref table"
Nov 25 15:32:49 thinkpad kcheckpass[3517]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Nov 25 15:32:49 thinkpad kcheckpass[3517]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for read
Nov 25 15:32:49 thinkpad kcheckpass[3517]: pam_tally(kde:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Nov 25 15:32:49 thinkpad kcheckpass[3517]: pam_tally(kde:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Nov 25 16:03:00 thinkpad kcheckpass[3770]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Nov 25 16:03:00 thinkpad kcheckpass[3770]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for read
Nov 25 16:03:06 thinkpad kcheckpass[3770]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Nov 25 16:03:06 thinkpad kcheckpass[3770]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for read
Nov 25 16:03:06 thinkpad kcheckpass[3770]: pam_tally(kde:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Nov 25 16:03:06 thinkpad kcheckpass[3770]: pam_tally(kde:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
```

Comment: Does it work with the current vanilla kernel? Have you tried using the kernel's native modesetting instead of the intel driver? Also, just pasting the Xorg log errors is not that helpful, the whole log would be more informative.

Comment: @jasonwryan, yes, this is with KTS. I hadn't have intel driver installed. Now I have it and seemingly it works. I will retain the question open for awhile until I ensure that it works properly. Thank you.

Comment: @foki what intel drivers? aren't they part of the kernel? I've had some flickering issues for a while now and not had time to investigate... here I am

Comment: @Robbo there are some drivers included in kernel but those are mostly generic. Here is driver search order for Xorg - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Driver_installation. What solved the problem for me was xf86-video-intel. No additional settings are needed, just installed it and it was being used by Xorg as suggested in search order.

Comment: @foki hmm I had uninstalled that for other issues I think and I remember seeing it was usually recommended to not use it anymore. But will install again and see how I go.